# this code is producing an error.."System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid."

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT distinct MbrBtch from Member where MbrStrm='"+DrpDwnStrm .SelectedItem .Text +"'";
            cmd1.Connection = con;
            DataTable Table1;
            Table1 = new DataTable("mbr");
            DataRow Row1;
            DataColumn MbrBatch = new DataColumn("MbrBatch");
            MbrBatch.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
            Table1.Columns.Add(MbrBatch);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader RdrMbr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                while (RdrMbr.Read())
                {

                    Row1 = Table1.NewRow();
                    Row1["MbrBatch"] = Convert.ToInt32(RdrMbr.GetInt32(0));
                    Table1.Rows.Add(Row1);
                }
                RdrMbr.Close();
            }

            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            DrpDwnBtch.DataSource = Table1;
            this.DrpDwnBtch.DataTextField = "MbrBatch";
            DrpDwnBtch.DataBind();

//here MbrBtch is numeric type attribute of sql server.
```

Comment: Where? What have you tried? etc.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: `Row1["MbrBatch"] = Convert.ToInt32(RdrMbr.GetInt32(0));` Smells.

Comment: You seeing if  DrpDwnStrm .SelectedItem is null? And MbrBatch muste be a Int in sql server. If not change the converstion type.

Comment: @pho3nix He would've gotten a null reference exception in this case, but I support him checking that, regardless of his problem.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be the below line gives you an error.

Change the line

```
    Row1["MbrBatch"] = Convert.ToInt32(RdrMbr.GetInt32(0));
```

with

```
int mbr = 0;
if (Int32.TryParse(RdrMbr[0], out mbr))
   Row1["MbrBatch"] = mbr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there are null values in the MbrBtch column? If so, you need to check for null like this:

```
if (!RdrMbr.IsDBNull(0))
    Row1["MbrBatch"] = Convert.ToInt32(RdrMbr.GetInt32(0));
else
    // Set value to what it should be if null, perhaps a -1 or 0
```